# Finding differences between two rows and adding them

Tags: linux, text-processing, awk

I want to use `awk` to add columns together but only to a maximum of 1 and only certain columns.

Here is what an input file I am working with looks like.

```
1   119 .   A   T   1000    PASS    MID=183;S=0;DOM=0.5;PO=1;GO=337;MT=1;AC=3;DP=1000;MULTIALLELIC  GT  0|0 1|0 0|0 0|0
1   119 .   A   T   1000    PASS    MID=362;S=0;DOM=0.5;PO=1;GO=562;MT=1;AC=2;DP=1000;MULTIALLELIC  GT  0|0 1|0 0|1 0|0
```

What I want it to look like

```
1   119 .   A   T   1000    PASS    MID=183;S=0;DOM=0.5;PO=1;GO=337;MT=1;AC=5;DP=1000   GT  0|0 1|0 0|1 0|0
```

So the only columns I need to add are AC=# and the 0's and 1's. The issues I am having are dealing with lines that have text in them and lines where both values are 1 (which I want to result in 1) as well as changing delimiters mid-file.

So far I have `awk 'NR%2 { split($0, a) ; next } { for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) printf " %d", a[i]+$i ; print "" } '`
Unfortunately this turns texts into 0's and doesn't output the ;'s, |'s, and tabs.

Comment: can you provide *representative* sample input, showing all of the changing delimiters?

Comment: The sample input I provided is exactly what I am working with. What I mean about changing delimiters is going from tab (from 1 to MID=) to semicolons, then back to tab (for the 0|0, 0|1,etc). Does this help or am I not understanding your question?

Comment: That helps, thanks. I assumed that but it wasn't clear at first if you had a messy file (with inconsistent delimiters) or just a complex file (with different, but consistent, delimiters internally, as you said)

Comment: @AMB. Would you please explain the output. Do you mean that you want the first row in the table except the column related to AC which should output the sum of the columns in the table?  The solution below will be updated according to your response!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Your table is very hard to deal with**, but one way of doing this is to break down the work to multiple steps. First of all save your data in a file called `data.txt`, then:

- convert the table to columns with fixed-widths and replace the spaces`" "` , the equal sign `=`, as well as the colon `";"` by columns `"\t"`. You can achieve this by combining functions from `sed` and `awk` as follows:

`sed 's/=/\t/g; s/;/\t/g' data.txt | awk '{printf "%-5s  %-5s %-5s %-5s %-5s %-5s %-5s %-5s %-5s %-5s %-5s %-5s %-5s %-5s %-5s %-5s %-5s %-5s %-5s%-5s %-5s %-5s %-5s %-5s %-5s %-5s %-5s %-5s %-5s %-5s\n", $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10,$11,$12,$13,$14,$15,$16,$17,$18,$19,$20,$21,$22,$23,$24,$25,$26,$27,$28,$29,$30,$31,$32,$33}'`

*output:*

```
1      119   .     A     T     1000  PASS  MID   183   S     0     DOM   0.5   PO    1     GO    337   MT    1    AC    3     DP    1000  MULTIALLELIC GT    0|0   1|0   0|0   0|0        
1      119   .     A     T     1000  PASS  MID   362   S     0     DOM   0.5   PO    1     GO    562   MT    1    AC    2     DP    1000  MULTIALLELIC GT    0|0   1|0   0|1   0|0
```

- Sum the values in a specific column, in your case column number `#21`. You can do this by piping the output of the previous step to the following command:

`awk '{ sum21+=$21} END {print sum21}')`

*output:*

```
5
```

-extract the first row from your table using the following command:

```
sed 's/=/\t/g; s/;/\t/g' data.txt| awk '{printf "%-5s  %-5s %-5s %-5s %-5s %-5s %-5s %-5s %-5s %-5s %-5s %-5s %-5s %-5s %-5s %-5s %-5s %-5s %-5s%-5s %-5s %-5s %-5s %-5s %-5s %-5s %-5s %-5s %-5s %-5s\n", $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10,$11,$12,$13,$14,$15,$16,$17,$18,$19,$20,$21,$22,$23,$24,$25,$26,$27,$28,$29,$30,$31,$32,$33}' | head -1
```

*output:*

```
1      119   .     A     T     1000  PASS  MID   183   S     0     DOM   0.5   PO    1     GO    337   MT    1    AC    3     DP    1000  MULTIALLELIC GT    0|0   1|0   0|0   0|0
```

-Replace the value of `field #21` from the previous step by the `sum-value` of column #21 and `reconstruct the spaces, colons and the other symbols` in your original table, as follows:

```
awk '{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8"="$9";"$10"="$11";"$12"="$13";"$14"="$15";"$16"="$17";"$18"="$19";"$20,"=",$21='$sum'";"$22"="$23";"$24,$25,$26,$27,$28,$29,$30,$31,$32,$33}'
```

*output:*

```
1 119 . A T 1000 PASS MID=183;S=0;DOM=0.5;PO=1;GO=337;MT=1;AC = 5;DP=1000;MULTIALLELIC GT 0|0 1|0 0|0 0|0
```

In a bash you can do it as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
sum_col21=$(sed 's/=/\t/g; s/;/\t/g' data.txt| awk '{printf "%-5s  %-5s %-5s %-5s %-5s %-5s %-5s %-5s %-5s %-5s %-5s %-5s %-5s %-5s %-5s %-5s %-5s %-5s %-5s%-5s %-5s %-5s %-5s %-5s %-5s %-5s %-5s %-5s %-5s %-5s\n", $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10,$11,$12,$13,$14,$15,$16,$17,$18,$19,$20,$21,$22,$23,$24,$25,$26,$27,$28,$29,$30,$31,$32,$33}' | awk '{ sum21+=$21} END {print sum21}')

first_row=$(sed 's/=/\t/g; s/;/\t/g' data.txt| awk '{printf "%-5s  %-5s %-5s %-5s %-5s %-5s %-5s %-5s %-5s %-5s %-5s %-5s %-5s %-5s %-5s %-5s %-5s %-5s %-5s%-5s %-5s %-5s %-5s %-5s %-5s %-5s %-5s %-5s %-5s %-5s\n", $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10,$11,$12,$13,$14,$15,$16,$17,$18,$19,$20,$21,$22,$23,$24,$25,$26,$27,$28,$29,$30,$31,$32,$33}' | head -1)


echo $first_row | awk '{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8"="$9";"$10"="$11";"$12"="$13";"$14"="$15";"$16"="$17";"$18"="$19";"$20,"=",$21='$sum_col21'";"$22"="$23";"$24,$25,$26,$27,$28,$29,$30,$31,$32,$33}'
```

**This solution will be updated following additional required clarifications in the text of the question.**

Comment: This works great, thank you. How would I add together the 0|0, 0|1, etc. columns added together. So in the example the output should read 0|0 1|0 0|1 0|0. Adding straight down the column EXCEPT when there are two 1's, which I need to just remain 1. 

So far I have  `awk '{for(i=26;i<=NF;i++){printf "%s ", $i}; printf "\n"}' ` which rips out the 0's and 1's that I wish to add.  Then if I use a delimiter of  "| "  I get each set of values I wish to sum. The issue now is: 
1) Adding the columns with a maximum value of 1
2) Ignoring the character | and spaces.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What is the purpose of the code you sent? It seems it just changes the | to a comma. Perhaps I am not running it correctly. Is there a way awk can sum and ignore the delimiter? If I just run `awk '{sum1+=$1} END {print sum1}' ` I get just a 1 or a 0 for the entire column, instead of 2 values. Or perhaps I need to go character by character and re-paste the delimiter between each summed value?

Hopefully I am making sense and on the right path.

Comment: The command I sent will remove tabs, spaces make your table a table. Then you can apply awk again to sum the columns you want ;-)